# Checking the value of a word in different dictionary then in the loop

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary, foreach

I've got two dictionaries, I am looking through one of them and want to do the math only if the value of the same key in other dictionary is more then 5.

How can I make the if statement correctly?

```
foreach (var word in dict1)
{              
    temp = word.Value;

    // something like this:
    if (temp in dict2 > 5)
    {
        A *= temp;
    }
    else
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: `value of the same key in other dictionary` - do you mean `dict2[word.Key]`?  you need `if (dict2[word.Key]>5)` probably

Comment: yeah, right.. i tried with dict2[temp] and then forgot totaly it's value not key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Dictionary for both dict1 and dict2:

```
foreach(var word in dict1.Where(w=>dict2.ContainsKey(w.Key) && dict2[w.Key]>5))
{
    //dowork
}
```

This iterates only the items in dict1 that have a value greater than 5 in dict2 and does some work.

Edit: Added dict2.ContainsKey(w.Key) check in Where clause since it is possible that dict2 won't contain a key in dict1.

Comment: Very good answer, since this addresses the possibility of keys not being present in the second dictionary. Could be faster with a `TryGetValue`, but would also become more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, with better error handling, should do it. This assumes that `word.key` is the correct key to be used to find the value in `dict2`.

```
if (dict2[word.key] > 5)
{
   A *= temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As ASh said it was simply:

```
if(dict2[word.Key]>5){}
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

to go a linq-heavy route from what's been mentioned

```
dict1.Keys
    .Intersect(dict2.Keys)     // We only care about keys in both dictionaries
    .Where(k => dict2[key] > 5)// We only care when the value in dict2 is greater than 5
    .Select(l => dict1[k])     // Get the values from dict1
```